# Control resizing mathematics

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

Ok... So I've got this pretty killer Screenshot system I've been using for a while... It pretty much involves creating a somewhat transparent Form that auto-sizes to fit all monitors... Which gives the screen(s) a "dark-out" effect... I then have a hidden "button" control whos position is set upon mouse-down... Then, until mouse-up, the button will resize in real-time to create a sort of "selection" area... The Button is granted full transparency to implement this effect.

Source Example: http://db.tt/LWxfDB6 [Also posted below]

I'm having two issues that are directly related, I believe.

1.) The coordinates are off for multimonitors, it properly returns the coordinates that are clicked upon (highlighted), but the highlight box (effect) is often on the wrong monitor.

2.) You can only select from top-left ---> bottom-right and not universal.

Sorry if I didn't explain it well, the source should explain better.
Thanks, in advance, for any and all help received. :)

**:MarkRect.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
```

namespace TW_Media_Chat_
{
    public partial class MarkRect : Form
    {
        Point Point1;
        Point Point2;
        public MarkRect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Programatically maximize to all monitors
            Screen[] Screens = Screen.AllScreens;
            int AllWidth = 0;
            int AllHeight = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < Screens.Length; index++)
            {
                AllWidth += Screens[index].Bounds.Width;
                AllHeight += Screens[index].Bounds.Height;
            }
            this.Width = AllWidth;
            this.Height = AllHeight;

```
    }

    private void Transparency_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button1.Location = Cursor.Position;
        Point1 = Cursor.Position;
    }
    private void Transparency_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        Point2 = Cursor.Position;
        AjaxChatBridge.AjaxVars.Point1 = Point1;
        AjaxChatBridge.AjaxVars.Point2 = Point2;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void MarkRect_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Width = Cursor.Position.X - this.button1.Left;
        this.button1.Height = Cursor.Position.Y - this.button1.Top;
    }
}
```

}

**:MarkRect.Designer.cs:**

```
namespace TW_Media_Chat_
{
    partial class MarkRect
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 172);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(19, 18);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.button1.Visible = false;
        // 
        // MarkRect
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(490, 406);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "MarkRect";
        this.Opacity = 0.5D;
        this.Text = "Transparency";
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Transparency_MouseDown);
        this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MarkRect_MouseMove);
        this.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Transparency_MouseUp);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should implement control resizing logic easier:

   void MarkRect_MouseMove(...)
   {
       var mouseX = Cursor.Position.X;
       var originalMouseX = Point1.X;

   ```
   button1.Left = Math.Min(mouseX, originalMouseX);
   button1.Width = Math.Abs(mouseX - originalMouseX);

   // the same for Y
   ```

   }
2. You should post that code here. We are to lazy to go to your dropbox to see the code. There are easier questions to answer here.

Comment: I would have to argue that DropBox better serves my purpose; To download the source for testing, as the majority of it is Designer code, but for the sake of others who share your opinion, It has been edited into the question. [Or will be in 30 seconds].

Comment: P.S. Your solution solution fixed the universal selection issue. I don't have multi-monitors to test on atm, but I'll comment when I get access to a set. :)

What about returning the button coordinates now? It completely nullified the structure I was using before, and I can't seem to get it. :/

Comment: @BinaryBrother, my solution wasn't targeting multiscreen issue since I have no experience in such things.

Comment: @BinaryBrother, what structure are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was referring to the method I used previously... To return the mouse-down and mouse-up coordinates to give me a good idea of the selection rectangle so I could pass those coordinates onto a Screenshot function. Now the coordinates may be reversed, which fixes the issue with inverted selection and control resizing mathematics, but completely broke my Screenshot function. I might revise my question and mark this one as answered, then ask about the other issue in a different question (thread). (Since it is 2 different issues). Would that be best?